# How to assign a default value to a newly defined field?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

It's my first experience with ByteBuddy and I'd like to dynamically create a subclass of `java.lang.Object` with only one public field named *myValue* of type `java.lang.String` and a default value of "Hello World !".
Unfortunately, after calling the myClass.newInstance() the field's value is `null` (within the Eclipse debugger).

```
final Class<?> myClass = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class).name("test.MyClass")
    .defineField("myValue", String.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
    .value("Hello World !")
    .make()
    .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION).getLoaded();
Object myObject = myClass.newInstance();
```

Am I missing something here ?

I'm using Eclipse Mars.2, an Oracle JDK 1.7.0_75 and ByteBuddy-1.2.3

Comment: I'm confused why you want to do this?

Comment: The reason is not really relevant as I'm just exploring the library (as the "Hello World !" value suggests). The class I'd like to emulate would look like this :
`package test;
public class MyClass {
public int myValue = "Hello World !";
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `value` method is writing a *constant pool default value* for a field what is  only possible in Java for `static` fields. Byte Buddy should throw an exception in this scenario and not suppress the error silently. I will change this behavior for the next version and update the *javadoc* to be more clear about what the `value` method is doing.

If you want to set a field value, you need to intercept any constructor to set the field value. You can do this in different ways such as using a `MethodDelegation` in combination with a `@FieldProxy` annotation. The documentation shows examples of how this can be done.

Comment: I was suspecting the `value` method's purpose was not to set the corresponding field's value. I agree that the javadoc could be more explicit. Thank you for your feedback and keep up the good work !